# How can I use Scala's Manifest class to instantiate the erased class at runtime?

Tags: generics, reflection, scala, manifest, instantiation

I'm doing some WebDriver+PageObject stuff.

(If your not familiar with PageObjects, this is a pattern where you have a class representing each page on your site which exposes all the functions of the page using the domain language, hiding the HTML stuff from the test.)

I want to be lazy and have one 'submit' method in my abstract Page class that all my other Pages extend from. I also want this method to new up the next Page subclass and return it.

Here is what I have in the Page class:

```
def submitExpecting[P <: Page[P]](implicit m: Manifest[_]): P = {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click
  m.erasure.getConstructor(classOf[WebDriver]).newInstance(driver).asInstanceOf[P]
}
```

and here's how I'm calling it:

```
val userHomePage = userSignupPage
      .login("graham")
      .acceptTermsAndConditions
      .submitExpecting[UserHomePage]
```

Compiling this, I get:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter m: Manifest[_]
.submitExpecting[UserHomePage]
```

I thought I was being smart, but clearly I'm not. ;)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your `Manifest` be related to the type parameter, i.e.

```
def submitExpecting[P <: Page[P]](implicit m: Manifest[P]): P
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ben's answer, you may want to consider using the Scala 2.8.x syntax:

```
def submitExpecting[P <: Page[P] : Manifest]: P
```

Afterwards, you can access the manifest via the `manifest[P]` construct. It feels a little cleaner overall (at least to me...)