# What are the limitations of Scala's Manifests?

Tags: generics, scala, manifest, reification

Scala's `Manifest`s are a way to get around some type erasure problems due to the JVM's lack of reified generics.

They are discussed in several other questions; here are a few:

- [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)
- [How does Scala's (2.8) Manifest work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587286/how-does-scalas-2-8-manifest-work)
- [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter)
- [How can I use Scala's Manifest class to instantiate the erased class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890358/how-can-i-use-scalas-manifest-class-to-instantiate-the-erased-class-at-runtime)
- [Manifest vs ClassManifest. What does this Scala error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991215/manifest-vs-classmanifest-what-does-this-scala-error-mean)

One of the comments mentions that “This feature is experimental, and there are cases in which it doesn't work. Still, it can go a long way.” (Daniel Sobral)

What are the cases where the Manifest approach breaks down and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important case should be open Tickets in the Scala teams bug tracking system. I found the following:

- [manifests + intersection types violate val-binding abstraction](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4110)
- [Compiler cannot determine implicit Manifest for type constructor](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2915)
- [ClassManifest.typeArguments returns empty list on array manifests](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3758)
- [manifests need to account for variance](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3051)

I believe the general idea is, that Manifests will be part of the planned/upcomming Scala reflection library and apart from using them in the context of Arrays is "on your own risk" ( [see](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Bug-ridden-Manifests-td2325417.html) ).

Answer (score 3):

One more:

```
    scala> class C;
    defined class C

    scala> trait T;
    defined trait T

    scala> manifest[C] <:< manifest[C with T]
    res0: Boolean = true
```

I've not even reported it since, according to [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3051?focusedCommentId=57905&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-57905), manifests are deprecated in 2.10 so they are not fixing bugs with them.